# Travelling with mobile phones with discharged batteries

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, electronic-items, power

I seem to recall some rule coming in to force about not being able to board a flight with a mobile phone that had a flat battery (wouldn't turn on) (introduced for security reasons)

**Is this enforced?** (I.e. Are there spot checks at certain airports or on certain airlines, which ones?)

**What could the consequences be for not having the phone charged?**

Answer (score 4):

Airport security officers may, randomly, ask that you turn on electronic devices (usually do something to activate the display) to show that they are functional. To do this, the battery must not be completely discharged. If you are unable to turn on the device, they may not allow you to bring the electronic device through the checkpoint and you would have to dispose of it or otherwise arrange to get it to your destination (or, perhaps, find a charger).

This related to a US TSA program, as discussed by the TSA in [this press release](https://www.tsa.gov/news/releases/2014/07/06/enhanced-security-measures-certain-airports-overseas), [this blog post](http://blog.tsa.gov/2014/07/tsa-travel-tips-enhanced-security.html), and [this BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-28185149). While the TSA does not screen passengers outside the US, it does work with the authorities in other countries. Other countries do perform similar checks as part of their security program, even for flights not involving the US, or if they detect anomalies on an X-ray. The UK, for example, [advises](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/electronic-devices-and-electrical-items) that electronic device batteries should be charged for all flights in or out of the UK.

This is not an entirely new procedure. Asking travelers to briefly turn on laptops was something that occasionally happened even pre-9/11.

In my experience, such checks are rare, but can happen randomly. I've been asked by the TSA in the US and once at a pre-boarding check on SWISS in Zurich flying into the US.

Comment: Mainly US or Just Anywhere?

Comment: Numerous times I have had to turn on my laptop at security check in Newark(EWR) and Minneapolis(MSP) pre-9/11.

Comment: It is very seldom, correct. But if it hits you, you are one mobile phone poorer. Also, depending on airport, they might test it more often - MUC for examples asks me to switch on and demonstrate the working of all three cameras I carry, every time I fly from there; but no other airport in the world ever cared about them.